# How to Load data in CSV file with a query in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a CSV file which contain millions records/rows. The header row is like:

```
<NIC,Name,Address,Telephone,CardType,Payment>
```

In my scenario I want to load data "CardType" is equal to "VIP". How can I preform this operation without loading whole records in the file into a staging table?

I am not loading these records into a data warehouse. I only need to separate these data in CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't super-clear, but it sounds like you want to do some processing of the rows before outputting them back into another CSV file. If that's the case, then you'll want to make use of the various transforms available, notably Conditional Split. In there, you can look for rows where CardType == VIP and send those down one output (call it "Valid Rows"), and send the others into the default output. Connect up your valid rows output to your CSV destination and that should be it.

Comment: Thanks siride ..  I managed  to do it with Conditional Split.That works...
But I want to know whether is  there a way that we can query the csv source directly like we do in excel sources?

Comment: @DulshankadeSilva: no. CSV is just a flat data provider. It grabs rows from the file and sends them straight on through.